# Cannot read property 'open' of undefined when opening react-native-sqlite-storage database from ios

Tags: ios, sqlite, react-native

I'm trying to use react-native-sqlite-storage to work with the local db on react native, for ios.

```
var SQLite = require('react-native-sqlite-storage');
var db = []; 

export default class DataBase {
  constructor () {
    db = SQLite.openDatabase("eventHelper.db", "1.0", "EventHelper", 200000, this.openCB, this.errorCB);
  }

  errorCB(err) {
    console.log("SQL Error: " + err);
  }

  successCB() {
    console.log("SQL executed fine");
  }

  openCB() {
    console.log("Database OPENED");
  }
}
```

But i get the following error message: Cannot read property 'open' of undefined.
I don't know exactly how does openDatabase works, i have not created the database. I am not sure wether i should create the database first, and how, or if openDatabase is doing this if the database does not exist.

I looked for this problem, and i tried the solution suggested here https://github.com/andpor/react-native-sqlite-storage/issues/64 
- uninstalled react-native-sqlite-storage
- removed the node_modules folder
- npm install
- npm install --save react-native-sqlite-storage
- rnpm link

but my build fails[image]

Any suggestion will be highly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Did you re-run react-native run-ios after you installed the SQLite plugin?
I got the same error and that fixed it, hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

A simple usage example ( currently I'm using it in a production app )

```
var SQLite = require('react-native-sqlite-storage');
var db = SQLite.openDatabase({name : "db.sqlite", location: 'default'});

db.executeSql("SELECT * FROM users WHERE userName=?",['user1'],
            (results) => {
              console.log(results);
            },
            (err) => {
              console.log(err);
            }
            );
```

Comment: i have some issues with the sqlite in react native, can you help me please ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Expo in your application, this issue happens because of conflicting imports.

To fix this, just do this:

```
import * as SQLite from "expo-sqlite";
//and when you want to initialize your db
const db = SQLite.openDatabase("test.db");
```

Instead of:

```
import SQLite from "react-native-sqlite-storage"
```

Hope this helps anyone still facing this problem.